# MySQL workbench error 1064 when adding trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am new to SQL and more specifically using MySQL Workbench.

I have created a database with two tables Grades and GPAList.

I want to take the average value of every entry in Grades (grouped by student id [sid is the name of the column]) once I have those averages, store them in the GPAList table with their corresponding students. This is intended to trigger every time a new entry is added to Grades.

This is the trigger that I have created:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `ProjectName`.`Grades_AFTER_UPDATE_1` AFTER UPDATE ON `Grades` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT sid, SUM ( CASE grade
                    when 'A' then 4.0
                    when 'B' then 3.5
                    when 'C' then 3.0
                    when 'D' then 2.5
                    when 'F' then 1.0
                    else 0
                end
                ) / COUNT(*) Grades
INTO GPAList
FROM Grades
GROUP BY sid;
END
```

The error that I am encountering is:

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
 corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at 
line 1 SQL Statement:  CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER 
`ProjectName`.`Grades_AFTER_UPDATE_1` AFTER UPDATE ON `Grades` FOR EACH ROW 
FOLLOWS `Grades_AFTER_UPDATE`
```

When I write this code in the workbench, no syntax errors are shown. When I try to apply this trigger, my code is converted to:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `ProjectName`.`Grades_AFTER_UPDATE_1`;

    DELIMITER $$
    USE `ProjectName`$$
    CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `ProjectName`.`Grades_AFTER_UPDATE_1` AFTER UPDATE ON `Grades` FOR EACH ROW FOLLOWS `Grades_AFTER_UPDATE`
    $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Only after clicking apply once more do I see the 1064 error listed above. Is there some easy fix that I am missing?

There is a Grades_AFTER_UPDATE that Grades_AFTER_UPDATE_1 is following, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  What is `GPAList`?  Why are you selecting two values into a single variable?  Why are you selecting multiple rows into a single variable?

Comment: @GordonLinoff GPAList was intended to be the table. I think I may be misunderstanding the proper use of `INTO`

Comment: So I figured out a partial solution: combine the two triggers into one since they both occur after an update. However, now whenever I change the value of grade in table Grade, an error is thrown (likely because of the first trigger). @GordonLinoff

Comment: That was the issue, and your code worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to store *all* averages after a single insert, but the correct insert logic is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO GPALIST(sid, grades)
    SELECT sid,
           AVG (CASE grade
                    when 'A' then 4.0
                    when 'B' then 3.5
                    when 'C' then 3.0
                    when 'D' then 2.5
                    when 'F' then 1.0
                    else 0
                 end) as Grades
   FROM Grades
   GROUP BY sid;
```

I suspect the trigger would want to access `new.` somewhere along the way.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response; I have swapped your code for everything between BEGIN and END in my original code, and I am still getting the exact same 1064 error as before. As for why I would want to store all averages, as I said earlier, I am a beginner, and for the moment I am not particularly concerned with efficiency.